# smb.conf read only any user no password

Tags: linux, samba

I want to host a path over samba which any user can read without a password.

In smb.conf on my host PC:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[mystuff]
   path = /path/to/my/stuff
   read only = yes
   public = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   browseable = yes
```

On some other computer if I

```
smbclient -L //myhostpc/mystuff
```

it says

```
Enter WORKGROUP\myusername's password:
```

Interestingly, it still says this if I miss-spell `mystuff`. The host PC was restarted, and `nmblookup -S WORKGROUP` lists entries for MYHOSTPC.

I also tried (on ubuntu, with cifs-utils installed)

```
sudo mount -t cifs //myhostpc/mystuff /tmp/mystuff
```

but get

```
Password for root@//myhostpc/mystuff
```

and if I try

```
sudo mount -t cifs //myhostpc/mystuff -o username=guest,password="" /tmp/mystuff
```

(as I saw somewhere), I get

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page)
```

I notice in `/var/log/samba/log.`:

```
[2022/02/12 14:57:23.569070,  0] ../../source3    /smbd/service.c:166(chdir_current_service)
  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/path/to/my/stuff) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=65534, gid=65534, 1 groups: 65534
```

What do I need to make `[mystuff]` visible on other computers, for any user, without asking for a password?

Comment: Read the man page, it's all there on how you supply a password if one is required. It can be supplied ion the command line or in a file.

Comment: Read the question. I want to NOT supply a password. I want there to BE no password.

Comment: What are your `[global]` settings? Do you have other shares on the same server which will still need normal accounts?

Comment: @user1686 I added `[global]` above

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `smbclient` mentions this specific situation:

> **`password`** [...] There is no default password. If no password is supplied on the command line (either by using this parameter or adding a password to the `-U` option (see below)) and the `-N` option is not specified, the client will prompt for a password, even if the desired service does not require one. (If no password is required, simply press ENTER to provide a null password.)

and later, referencing the `-N` that this mentioned:

> **`-N`|`--no-pass`** If specified, this parameter suppresses the normal password prompt from the client to the user. This is useful when accessing a service that does not require a password.

The solution in your case?

```
smbclient -NL //myhostpc/mystuff
```

The same effect is available for `mount`. Here from `man mount.cifs` (searching for references to `password`):

> **`password=arg`|`pass=arg`** specifies the CIFS password. If this option is not given then the environment variable `PASSWD` is used. If the password is not  specified  directly  or  indirectly  via an argument to mount, `mount.cifs` will prompt for a password, unless the `guest` option is specified.

which leads us to the `guest` option:

> **`guest`** don't prompt for a password

The solution for you here?

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //myhostpc/mystuff /tmp/mystuff
```